# Cannot access DOM object through createRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference

I'm very new to React JS. I'm trying to access the dom object of an iframe for changing its size.

I have the iframe in my render - `<iframe ref={this.myRef} ></iframe>`

And in the constructor, I have

`this.myRef = React.createRef()`

When I console log(this.myRef.current),  I get back null eventhough when I console (this.myRef), it is shown to have current inside it and it holds many objects.

Comment: Are u sure that the iframe is loaded before your constructor being triggered ?

Comment: Thanks. I think that is the problem, when I console logged this.myRef in componentDidMount, I got the object.

Answer (score 0):

I was on 'react-dom' version 16.0.0 , I upgraded to the latest - 16.7.0 , and it started working!